# Android browser garbles events for two taps in quick succession

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, touchstart

I'm trying to use JavaScript and jQuery to capture touch events. But I'm seeing some very odd behavior in the Web browser on Android 2.3.2: whenever I tap the screen, and then quickly tap somewhere else on the screen, the browser:

- momentarily shows an orange border and highlight over the entire screen, **and**
- sends me the wrong events.

The orange border seems to be just a related symptom of the same underlying problem, so I'm not too worried about it -- it's actually convenient for being able to tell when the browser is screwing things up. What I really want to know is, **how can I consistently get the right touch events for two quick taps?** I believe that when that problem is solved, the orange border will go away as well.

What follows are all the painful details I've worked out so far.

[Here's a page that shows the problem](http://sandbox.excastle.com/stackoverflow/android-tap-twice.html) and displays lots of diagnostic information about the details and timing of each event that's received. You're sure to get the orange flash / bad events if you tap inside the blue rectangle, then quickly tap inside the black rectangle.

My jQuery code is pretty standard. The `log` function's implementation isn't important; the problem is that the browser doesn't call it when it should.

```
el = $('#battle');
el.on('touchstart', function(event) {
  log(event);
  return event.preventDefault();
});
el.on('touchend', function(event) {
  return log(event);
});
el.on('touchcancel', function(event) {
  return log(event);
});
el.mousedown(function(event) {
  log(event);
  return event.preventDefault();
});
return el.mouseup(function(event) {
  return log(event);
});
```

More details on the phenomena I described initially:

*Orange border and highlight:* This is the same orange border and highlight that the browser draws around a hyperlink when you click it. But there are no hyperlinks on the page, and the browser draws this orange border around the whole screen -- or more specifically, around the outer `<div id="battle">` that I'm hooking events on via jQuery.

*Wrong events:* In my `touchstart` event handler, I'm calling `event.preventDefault()`, to tell the browser not to scroll, not to synthesize mouse events, etc. Therefore, I expect to get only `touchstart` and `touchend` events. And I do, for the first tap. But instead of `touchstart`/`touchend` for the second tap, I get all number of combinations of touch events, synthesized mouse events, and the occasional `touchcancel` for the second tap, or even repeated events for the first tap. Details below.

This behavior also only occurs in very particular circumstances:

- The first tap must be short (less than ~200ms).
- The second tap must come quickly thereafter (less than ~450ms after the first tap's `touchstart`).
- The second tap must be at least 150 pixels away from the first tap (measured along the diagonal from the coordinates of the first tap's `touchstart`).
- If I remove my code that hooks `mousedown` and `mouseup`, the orange rectangles no longer appear. However, the touch events are sometimes still garbled.

As far as what I mean by the events being garbled, here's what I see. When I write "1:", that means the events are for the first tap's coordinates; "2:" means the second tap's coordinates. I saw the following patterns of events (percentages indicate how many times each one came up after 100 trials):

- (50%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 1:mousedown 1:mouseup (short delay) 2:mousedown 2:mouseup
- (35%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 2:touchstart 1:mousedown 1:mouseup 2:touchend
- (10%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 2:touchstart 1:mousedown 1:mouseup 2:touchcancel (short delay) 2:mousedown 2:mouseup
- (3%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 2:touchstart 2:touchend (short delay) 1:mousedown 1:mouseup
- (2%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 1:mousedown 1:mouseup *(and nothing at all for the second tap)*

Some combinations of events seem to come up more often depending on how quickly I tap, but I haven't quite nailed down the pattern. (Two quick, crisp taps seem more likely to come in under the second item above, whereas a more rapid-fire approach with less emphasis on crispness seems more likely to be the first item. But I haven't identified specific timing numbers that lead to each.) Similarly, the "short delays" indicated above can be anywhere from ~150ms to ~400ms; I haven't reverse-engineered the whole pattern there either.

If I don't hook `mousedown` and `mouseup`, the distribution is roughly this:

- (40%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 2:touchstart 2:touchcancel
- (35%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend 2:touchstart 2:touchend *(the actual desired behavior)*
- (25%) 1:touchstart 1:touchend *(and nothing at all for the second tap)*

So if I don't hook the mouse events, it works a third of the time; and if I was willing to pretend that `touchcancel` meant the same thing as `touchend`, I could get that up to 75% of the time. But that's still pretty sucky.

Alternatives I've already tried:

- I've tried using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)'s [`vmousedown` and `vmouseup` events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html), but they aren't always triggered for the second tap, I suspect because of this same underlying event weirdness.
- I could just forget about touch events entirely and only use the synthesized mouse events, but there's usually about a half-second delay between the physical tap and the delivery of the synthesized mouse event, whereas the touch events are immediate so I can be more responsive. I also want to prevent scrolling -- this is for a fullscreen game, and I'd rather not have the user accidentally scrolling the address bar back into view and blocking part of the game -- and doing `preventDefault` on the `touchstart` usually achieves that (though occasionally the second tap is actually able to scroll the screen despite my `preventDefault`... another reason I want to solve this whole event mess).
- I've tried a third-party Web browser ([Dolphin](http://www.dolphin-browser.com/)), but it has the same problems with events. So I'm guessing it's probably a problem with the way the underlying WebView delivers events to scripts.

Can anyone suggest a way to change my HTML, my event handlers, or anything else in order to reliably get touch events for two quick taps in succession?

Comment: It is working fine on my Galaxy Tablet (3.0). I have this problem on small GingerBread phone (2.3.4). I think I was able to solve it using my own webView but the problem is that I can not read the table because the phone is small; But for sure, the orange is not appearing anymore. Do you intend to use a WebView or that is not an option.?

Comment: @Sherif, currently I'm just putting files on a Web server, but I have some vague plans to try to make it into a PhoneGap app at some point. Does that answer your question about WebView? (I know basically nothing about Android development at this point -- I was just trying to get this to work in a browser. But I can always learn.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having tried to develop multi-touch HTML5 games in the Android browser (and trying them in other Android compatible browsers too), I think Android 2.x's browser simply does not properly support touch input.  For starters, it doesn't support multi-touch which makes some kinds of game unplayable.  (Obviously the *phone* supports multi-touch because you can pinch zoom etc., but the *browser* doesn't.)  Then there are lots of problems with latency, touches 'sticking' and so on.  I vaguely remember reading something about the phone's drivers for touch inputs not really working with true multitouch (i.e. it can detect either single touch or pinch zooms and that's it), but I don't have any references to back that up...

Apparently Android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) fixes it.  So you might just have to wait for Android 4, which should be out soon anyway, and try again.  Beyond that, Google have announced they're planning to replace the Android Browser with a mobile version of Chrome in future, so hopefully at least by then our browser touch-input woes will be over.

Comment: I thought you couldn't even upgrade Android unless your device manufacturer released their own build of the OS, with their custom drivers and such. How realistic is it to expect people to upgrade? (honest question, don't know the answer)

Comment: The multitouch depends on the phone in question, but most of them do have true multitouch

Comment: @JoeWhite, you can't expect people to upgrade their Android version. Older phones don't receive the update from the manufacturer, so hacking it in is the only possibility. That's not something for novice users to do!

Comment: So basically this answer amounts to "you're screwed, you'll have to wait a few years until nobody is using Android 2 devices anymore"? That'd be a hell of a bummer if it's true. (Though the first comment on the question suggests that my specific problem may be fixed in Android 3, which is at least a little better than having to wait for Android 4 to penetrate the market.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a theory: Wasn't able to test extensively

According to the [init function in the soruce code of a webview](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView.init%28%29), the statement ***`setFocusable(true)`*** is always called on a webview during its initialisation.

When I tried to make the view not focusable anymore using ***`setFocusable(false)`*** the error did not happen again. It seems the orange box does not appear. I was testing this on a small samsung phone running os 2.3.4. What I am sure of is that this orange box did not re appear.

In case this turns out to be true, it is highly likely that we can solve this without our own webview. What makes things more complicated is if setting the focusable property to false triggers other problems.

Finally, I do not think we can control this property from javascript (or can we?). Maybe You can declare that a specific control or the whole document is not an input or something like that? I am only extrapolating so bare that this may be false.

***Edit: Regarding your comment on your question***
I just created a blank application with only a Webview that loads your url after setting its focusable property to false. Please, if you have more resources to test it, I will upload it for you to try it. [Here is the application](http://www.mediafire.com/?lysgejulvj87n0w)

Comment: The good news is, your application does prevent the orange rectangle. The bad news is, it doesn't prevent the events from getting garbled. The pattern of events looks about the same as when I'm just in the Web browser, including the problem of the second tap occasionally generating no events at all. Sigh. +1 for lateral thinking, though.

Comment: Ultimately, I think this will be the most productive answer. Based on the research that I did for this question, I think I'll probably be able to listen to both touch and mouse events, and ignore the mouse events that are duplicates of touch events. Then the biggest problem is the orange rectangles when a mouse event gets synthesized, which your answer gives me a way to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the jQuery Mobile events? You can find the decoupled widgets/plugins here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

You'll probably need jquery.mobile.event.js and jquery.mobile.vmouse.js

Now you can simply bind to the tap, swipe etc. events within jQuery. Or is it necessary to differentiate between the start and end of a tap?

Comment: As I mentioned toward the end of my question ("Alternatives I've already tried:"), I have tried jQuery Mobile's `vmousedown` and `vmouseup` events, and they suffer from the same problems -- sometimes the second tap simply doesn't fire any events. I assume the `tap` event would fail for the same reason (and besides, I'll need to support some custom gestures beyond what jQuery Mobile offers).

Answer (score 0):

instead of attach all event using on  you try this may be it works for you

```
 $("...").bind("mousedown touchstart MozTouchDown", function(e) {
   if(e.originalEvent.touches && e.originalEvent.touches.length) {
    e = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    } else if(e.originalEvent.changedTouches && e.originalEvent.changedTouches.length) {
    e = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
    }

// Handle mouse down
 });
```

Comment: So you mean, just use `bind` instead of `on`? I just tried that, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching the event directly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el, hypot, log, prev, resetTimeout, start, prevTouchX, prevTouchY;
    var resetTimeout = null;
    var start = null;
    var prev = null;
    var resetTimeout;

    var hypot = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        var dx, dy, h;
        dx = x2 - x1;
        dy = y2 - y1;
        h = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return Math.round(h * 10) / 10;
    };


    var logf = function(event) {
        var div, table, values, x, y, _ref, _ref2, _ref3, _ref4, _ref5, _ref6;
        if (event.type === "touchend"){
            x = prevTouchX;
            y = prevTouchY;
        } else {
            x = event.touches[0].pageX;
            y = event.touches[0].pageY;
            prevTouchX = x;
            prevTouchY = y;
        }
        div = $('.log :first');
        table = div.find('table');
        if (table.length === 0) {
            $('.log div:gt(1), .log hr:gt(0)').remove();
            table = $('<table border style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr>\n<th rowspan="2">Event</th>\n<th rowspan="2">X</th>\n<th rowspan="2">Y</th>\n<th colspan="4">From start</th>\n<th colspan="4">From prev</th>\n</tr><tr>\n<th>&Delta;T (ms)</th>\n<th>&Delta;X</th>\n<th>&Delta;Y</th>\n<th>Distance</th>\n<th>&Delta;T (ms)</th>\n<th>&Delta;X</th>\n<th>&Delta;Y</th>\n<th>Distance</th>\n</tr></table>');
            div.append(table);
        }
        values = {
            time: event.timeStamp,
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
        if (start == null) {
            start = values;
        }
        if (prev == null) {
            prev = values;
        }
        table.append("<tr>\n<td>" + event.type + "</td>\n<td>" + x + "</td>\n<td>" + y + "</td>\n<td>" + (event.timeStamp - start.time) + "</td>\n<td>" + (x - start.x) + "</td>\n<td>" + (y - start.y) + "</td>\n<td>" + (hypot(x, y, start.x, start.y)) + "</td>\n<td>" + (event.timeStamp - prev.time) + "</td>\n<td>" + (x - prev.x) + "</td>\n<td>" + (y - prev.y) + "</td>\n<td>" + (hypot(x, y, prev.x, prev.y)) + "</td>\n</tr>");
        prev = values;

        if(resetTimeout !== null){
            window.clearTimeout(resetTimeout)
        }
        resetTimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
            start = null;
            prev = null;
            $('.log').prepend('<hr/>');
        }, 1000);
    };
    var battle = document.getElementById("battle");
    battle.addEventListener("touchstart",logf,  false);
    battle.addEventListener("touchmove",function(e){logf(e);e.preventDefault();},  false);
    battle.addEventListener("touchend",logf,  false);
    battle.addEventListener("touchcancel",logf,  false);
});
```

(Sorry if the code is really sloppy, I wasn't really paying much attention to the log function, but I made to make some minor changes as it wasn't firing correctly at my touchend event as event.touches[0].pageX is undefined at that point. Also, I wrapped it in a ready function, because I was just being lazy :-P)

Since this is only tracking the first touch (event.touches[0]), you can probably make some adjustments to test multi-touch by going down the touches array. What I've discovered on my android device (gingerbread) was that if you have two fingers down on the screen simultaneously, the touchend event will only fire when the last touch is let go; i.e. the second finger release.

Also, when I attached the mousedown/mouseup event listeners, then I got the same exact thing you did with the whole orange highlight thingy.

The device I tested on was a Samsung Droid Charge with OTA Gingerbread update.

Comment: This doesn't fix the original problems, and introduces a new one. Occasionally it generates the expected events, but usually the second tap either generates no events at all, or (new behavior with your changes) generates a `touchstart` with no corresponding `touchend` or `touchcancel`.

Comment: Test page with your JavaScript substituted for mine: http://sandbox.excastle.com/stackoverflow/android-tap-twice-2.html Reproduces the problems I mentioned on my Vizio VTAB1008 running Android 2.3.2.